# How to load 1000+ Google Earth markers effectively?

Tags: javascript, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I have an array that contains over 1000+ markers for Google Earth.

At the moment I am looping through the array with a for loop which is causing the Earth to freeze until they have all loaded successfully.

Can anyone recommend the best way to handle this so it loads a lot quicker for visitors?

Ideally I was thinking of loading only those markers in view/bounds but haven't seen any documentation to support this idea.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You'd have to write your own method to check the bounds against the position of the marker; lots of apps do this now.

Comment: @Mathletics Have you seen any top line example of this in practice? Not too sure how lat/long equates to the bounds.

Comment: Yelp does this on the map-based search. A Google Map object has a method called `getBounds` that returns this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds which you can use to test. Did you read the API?

Comment: Yeah I have noticed a fair few differences between Earth vs Maps API - a lot is different but I will try and use Maps as an example and re-work it into Earth. The Earth API has a lot less working examples/documentation which is making it a little hard :)

Comment: Oh dang, sorry about that. I get so into the Maps stuff I forgot Earth had a different set. May not work the same for you then, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use [HTML5 WebWorkers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html#workers) to instantiate the markers asynchronously and then just use whatever method they have for show()/hide(), iterating through your objects.

It will only work in latest browsers, that implement WebWorkers, but i don't think there is another efficient way

Comment: Hmm yeah unfortunately I have to support IE7/8. I guess that means I am stuck!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to instead do this from the server using KML Updates:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/updates

Each update would load in 100 markers, say, and display them and then a second later it reloads and pulls the next 100 markers.